# Pointers in swift: purpose of UnsafeMutableBufferPointer

Tags: swift, pointers

Currently looking into swift pointers.

`UnsafePointer` and `UnsafeMutablePointer` provide a pointer to a byte. By using pointer arithmetic, you can access the rest of the bytes.

Something similar can be done with a `UnsafeMutableBufferPointer`, which has an endIndex parameter. So what is the advantage/difference of using `UnsafeMutableBufferPointer` over `UnsafeMutablePointer` when accessing for example the bytes in `NSData`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UnsafeMutablePointer<T>` is designed for accessing a single element of type `T`. Its interface is designed for accessing a single scalar value.

`UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<T>`, on the other hand, is designed to access a group of elements of type `T` stored in a contiguous block of memory. Its interface is designed to access individual elements of the range, and also for treating the entire collection as a single unit (e.g. the `generate` method).

If you access bytes inside `NSData`, `UnsafePointer` alone is not sufficient, because you need to know the length of data. In contrast, a single `UnsafeBufferPointer` is sufficient to represent the data, because it provides both the initial location and the number of elements.

Comment: You can keep track of the bytes manually by calling data.length. Although, now that I think of it, there is a risk here. NSData is not guaranteed to be continuous.